# JDA: How to detect how a Member got removed from the guild?

Tags: java, events, discord-jda

I want to send a message when a Member got kicked and a other if he was banned.

So in the docs of the JDA stands, that the onGuildMemberRemove Event includes Kick, Ban and Normal Leave.

```
    @Override
    public void onGuildMemberRemove(@NotNull GuildMemberRemoveEvent event) {

    }
```

But how should I now detect when a Member gots Banned or Kicked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [retrieveAuditLogs](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#retrieveAuditLogs()) and check if the user was recently targeted by a ban or kick.

Example:

```java
@Override
public void onGuildMemberRemove(GuildMemberRemoveEvent event) {
  event.getGuild()
       .retrieveAuditLogs()
       .queueAfter(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, (logs) -> { // Gotta wait a second for discord to populate the logs properly
         boolean isBan = false, isKick = false;
         for (AuditLogEntry log : logs) {
             if (log.getTargetIdLong() == event.getUser().getIdLong()) {
                 isBan = log.getType() == ActionType.BAN;
                 isKick = log.getType() == ActionType.KICK;
                 break;
             }
         }
         ... code here
       });
}
```

Comment: Could I also get the Member who kicked/banned the Member with Method ?

Comment: Yes [AuditLogEntry#getUser](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/audit/AuditLogEntry.html#getUser())

Comment: And is it also possibly to get the reason for the Kick, for Ban you can use retriveBanEntries, but for the kick is it possible to get the Reason from the AuditLogEntry ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this is by using the bot to kick or ban, since you can not differentiate between the user being kicked or banned or leaving 'normally' using the `GuildMemberRemoveEvent`.

For detecting bans you may use the `GuildBanEvent`, but be aware that it doesn't necessarily indicates that the user is indeed removed from the server.

If you use you bot to kick and ban user, you could send the custom message every time a kick or ban command is issued. If a user leaves and it wasn't subject of a command, you can send the normal message instead.